# Code Snippet can't be added to snippet library in Visual C# Express '08

Tags: c#, code-snippets

This snippet is added fine:

http://pastebin.com/m5f7f2dce

And this is the one I'm trying to add into my IDE:

http://pastebin.com/m61321572

But I recieve an "invalid snippet" error. I don't see anything different about the two except for the declaration area.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the same error if I save your snippet with Latin1 encoding.

The snippet successfully gets imported if you save it with UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: FYI, when you use an "ñ" character it automatically changes the encoding and apparently Visual Studio doesn't accept that type of encoding.